# Angular 6 - Template-driven Form - Check if email already exist

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

I am trying to check if the email that the user filled in the form to register already exists. I created a directive to check it but I don't know when to fetch the list of emails which already exist and how to pass it to the validator file. For the moment, I fetch the list of the users from the database in *"register.component.ts"*. Then I try to pass it in the html with *appEmailValidator="existingEmailsList"*. However, the *console.log(this.emailsList);* in the directive file prints the string existingEmailsList and not the list.

**Register.component.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form (submit)="register()" #registerForm="ngForm">

          <div id="emailField">
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
              <input matInput placeholder="Email" type="text" required appEmailValidator="existingEmailsList" email [(ngModel)]="credentials.email" name="email" #email="ngModel">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">
                Email is required.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">
                Email not valid.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="name.errors.Email">
                 Email already exists.
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="passwordField">
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
              <input matInput placeholder="Passwod" type="password" required minlength="7" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" name="password"
                #password="ngModel">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
                Password is required.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">
                Password must be at least 7 characters long.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!registerForm.form.valid">Register!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../services/authentication.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ApiService } from "../../services/api.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-register",
  templateUrl: "./register.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./register.component.scss"]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  credentials: any = {};
  existingEmailsList: any = [];

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private api: ApiService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        for (let item in data) {
          this.existingEmailsList.push(data[item].email);
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  register() {
    this.auth.register(this.credentials).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/profile");
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Email-Validator.directive.ts**

```
import {
  Validator,
  AbstractControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  ValidatorFn
} from "@angular/forms";
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";

export function compareEmails(emailsList: any): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    let alreadyExist = false;
    for (let email of emailsList) {
      if (email === control.value) {
        alreadyExist = true;
      }
    }
    return alreadyExist ? { Email: { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: "[appEmailValidator]",
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: EmailValidatorDirective,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class EmailValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input("appEmailValidator") emailsList: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    console.log(this.emailsList);
    return this.emailsList ? compareEmails(this.emailsList)(control) : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that `@Input("appEmailValidator") emailsList` should be of type [] or maybe string[].

Comment: I changed it like that @Input("appEmailValidator") emailsList: [string];
But it doesn't fix my problem. @Mikemike

Comment: Change the <input> so that it has `appEmailValidator [emailsList]="existingEmailsList"`. Then in the directive just put `@Input() ...`